# Drupal 7 hook_block_info and hook_block_view permission wise display

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a module that has permission hook for normal access and for administrative access. I want to display two different blocks to different set of users. Say,
the "admin" will only get to view one block and a "site owner" will see the other display.

So, till now what I have done is, declared 2 hook_block_info() as,

```
    $blocks = array();
//Block for the Normal Site Owners
$blocks['payouts'] = array(
    'info' => t('Listing of Payouts'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,

);
//Block for the Administrators
$blocks['commission_payments'] = array(
    .....
            .....
);
```

When I declare the hook_block_view() I use user_access() to restrict the user's to see it. 
But is there any way I can restrict the user's to view the block infos in the region settings ? Is there any array parameter for hook_block_info that can achieve this? I suppose the 'page' parameter will only handle the page where to display the block.

Comment: Just a note that depending on your needs you may not need to write code to accomplish this. See http://randyfay.com/node/77, which has a Views-oriented approach pointers to other approaches.

Comment: Actually, I have some custom tables to work upon. So, I have to work in custom module.
So, any other way outs ?

Comment: It's super easy to enable views for your custom tables. I'm not saying that's the most appropriate thing. But I'd provide views integration for *any* custom table that I ever wanted to view the data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is just to check the user role in `hook_block_view()`:

```
function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'payouts':
      if (in_array('Admin', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $block['content'] = t('Hello Admin');
      }
      break;

    case 'commission_payments':
      if (in_array('Site Owner', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $block['content'] = t('Hello Site Owner');
      }
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same trick that you do in block_view in your block_info.  The array returned from block_info forms the list for the Block page.  However, if a block has been enabled, it will no longer be visible, either in the Block page, or on your other pages (unless the user has permission).

[hook_block_list_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7) may also be an option for what you want, but is only D7 and up.